# Why is my new laptop slowing down during file copy/move operations?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, windows-8.1

I bought a new laptop(Asus X555L) three days ago. It has a 1TB HDD, 4 GB DDR3L RAM , i5 4th gen CPU and a 2GB graphic card.

When I copy/move files into the laptop it gets super slow. If you try to open Visual Studio or Photoshop  it takes a long time to open them. Sometimes opening a video file while doing a copy operation takes more time than usual. This didn't happen on my old laptop (Probook 4530s).

Does this mean my new laptop has some defect? When I'm not doing a file copy/move operation it's super fast.

Additional info: My old laptop had a Toshiba HDD and the new one has a Western Digital HDD.

Comment: How slow is super slow? Could you elaborate on that? For instance, try playing a video without any file transfers in progress and let us know how long it takes for the video to start playing. Then do so with a few file transfers in progress.

Comment: Also, a HDD benchmark test using [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html) or [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) could shed some light on this (not saying it will though).

Comment: 4th gen i5 cpus only support ddr3

Comment: @vinayak  Well without any file transfers in background everything works super fast. I actually used few benchmark tools. According to them  HDD performs great.  When I copy data from my external HDD into laptop's HDD via USB3 port, I get around 50 mbps

Comment: @luke Yeah you are right.  It was a typo. The ram is DDR3 low powered version.  The CPU is i5- 4210U

Answer (score 0):

Like many laptops without SSD, the disk speed of the ASUS X555L is not exactly fast - I did not find a configuration of the X555L with a WD 1TB disk, but those configurations I did find used average 5400rpm disks. Additionally there are some features which can slow down the disk even more and/or cause load on the processor on disk access (like a search indexer, file encryption, or an antivirus). In my experience the most frequent cause of this is an antivirus suite.

Open the Task Manager to see if something is killing the CPU. If you can't find anything try temporarily disabling the antivirus and see if the issue is resolved. If disabling the Antivirus resolves the issue, I advise searching for a different antivirus vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, when people asked questions like this, people would tell them to check that DMA mode is enabled on the hard drive and not PIO mode.  All these years later, sometimes DMA mode on the hard drive still doesn't get enabled, even with SATA drives.  You need to also make sure you have the newest chipset drivers for your motherboard, this will help speed up Disk I/O operations.  The easiest way to tell if it's a driver/DMA issue is to download Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and look at the Interrupt value while repeating your test.  If you see 20% or more of your CPU usage dedicated to interrupts, that means something is awry with the driver or the mode the hard drive is working in.

Beyond that, knowing the make and model of your HD will go a long way towards managing your expectations about it's speed, i.e. if it IS a 5400rpm HD... well you're not going to win Formula 1 in a Ford Fiesta.  Defragging will also ameliorate things, the slower the hard drive, the more it'll make a difference.  Good luck.